# Firebase fireproof promises throwing error

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise

I'm using Firebase and Fireproof (uses promises for firebase calls) and when I make a call to my firebase using fireproof like so:

```
var ref = new Firebase(firebasePath);
fp = new Fireproof(ref); 
fp.then(function(snap) { 
    console.log(snap.val()); 

});
```

I keep on getting the following error:

```
You must supply a Defer-style promise library to Fireproof!
```

I've gone through the documentation a number of times trying to figure out what I must of missed but cant find anything.

Comment: this does not look right. you probably need to call some query method on `fp` and that one will return your promise.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked out the problem.

I needed to do the following:

```
// Q being a promise library.
var Q = require('q');

Fireproof.bless(Q);
fp = new Fireproof(ref); 
fp.then(function(snap) { 
    console.log(snap.val()); 
});
```

I needed to pass through a promise library.